# Powershell calls another PS1 in loop finishes after first foreach loop run completes

Tags: powershell, loops, foreach, wrapper

I have 2 Powershell scripts, one which is the primary (ServerInfo.ps1) and a secondary script which is intended to work as a wrapper, launching the first script within a loop that will use different credentials on each loop due to queries being made to different AD Domains/Forests that require different domain creds for each respective domain.

The primary script runs fine when run on its own if I run it manually and locally from a machine in each respective domain, and does as needed (grabbing details from remote machines and exporting to a csv)

The following is the Wrapper script (domain name examples changed for security reasons).

```
# This is a Wrapper Script for ServerInfo.ps1
$username = Read-Host -Prompt 'Enter User Account to be used - Do not specify domain'
$Password = Read-Host -Prompt 'Input User Password - NOTE must be the same on all domains' -AsSecureString
$domains = "d1.contoso.com","d2.contoso.com","dev.contosodev1.com","test.contosotest1.com"
$Arguments = "-file c:\serverinfo\ServerInfo.ps1", "-ServerType 'DCs'"

ForEach ($domain in $domains) {
$Credential = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList "$domain\$username", $Password
Start-Process powershell.exe -Credential $credential -NoNewWindow -ArgumentList $Arguments -WorkingDirectory 'c:\Serverinfo\' -Wait
}
```

Specifically this will be used to query Domain Controllers with an elevated permissions account that is identical on each domain, as the account used on member computers does not have Builtin Admin or AD (Domain/Enterprise Admin) level rights on the Domain Controllers. The intention is also to run the scripts from a Domain member, not locally on a DC.

As the primary script (serverinfo.ps1) is over 1000 lines of code, I will simply say that with the wrapper passing the argument "-ServerType DCS", ServerInfo.ps1 initially grabs all Domain Controller names from AD of the respective domain the account belongs to, and performs things such as WMI & Registry queries of each DC, exporting the output to a CSV file.

For the first domain, this runs fine without any issue and the ServerInfo.ps1 script does it job querying every DC in the first domain, but then both PowerShell scripts close/stop running without it continuing to the second domain in the wrapper loop aka, the "foreach ($Domain in $Domains)" loop is not working once the first domain completes.

As I don't see any scripting error in the wrapper, and there is no Exit or other cancellation/Finish command in ServerInfo.Ps1, I am at a loss as to why the wrapper is not working as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> For the first domain, this runs fine without any issue and the
>   ServerInfo.ps1 script does it job querying every DC in the first
>   domain, but then both PowerShell scripts close/stop running without it
>   continuing to the second domain in the wrapper loop aka, the "foreach
>   ($Domain in $Domains)" loop is not working once the first domain
>   completes.

I am pretty sure that your loop works. Just insert a `Write-Host "Iteration for domain: $domain"` inside that loop and you will see, that it indeed iterates over all domains.

I am more concerned about the way you call that other script. With `Start-Process -Credential` the process will be executed in the user space of the provided user. In your scenario, this will require any trust relationships between your domains, if you want to run it on any domain computer for all domains. Do you have any?
If not, you have to pass the credentials to the called script in some secure way, so that it can authenticate itself when using remote control cmdlets.

Comment: Regarding your query:
In your scenario, this will require any trust relationships between your domains, if you want to run it on any domain computer for all domains. Do you have any?

Yes we do have trusts across most of the forests, so this neccesarily wont be an issue (we have 6 domains in the Prod forest, and I'll be running this from a Prod member computer and initiating the wrapper under my prod normal account from the same domain as the member computer, querying across all Prod domains DCs, plus also querying the seperate Test & Dev forest Domains DCs.

Comment: I have also taken the suggestion of adding in a write-host within the loop to report out the Domain being queried, and am currently running the query, but i know from the time length taken it will only complete the first domain and not query the others (the first domain consists of about 40 DCs internationally, so it takes about 1 hr to complete the first domain, and then the script stops, whereas I would expect it to take another 3+ hours to complete all the domains)

Comment: The script just completed, after it ran through the first domain only as I expected, although the write-host in the loop shows that it did actually loop through against all the domains but I have no visible error output to identify what did does not appear to have actually run powershell script against the other domains. I think I'll take a break here and debug this out a little more by running the command outside the loop targeting another domain to see what error i get back

Comment: Grabbed the $error output...
Start-Process : This command cannot be run due to the error: Logon Failure: The machine you are logging onto is protected by an authentication firewall. The specified account is not allowed to authenticate to the machine.
At line:11 char:1
+ Start-Process powershell.exe -Credential $credential -NoNewWindow -Wo ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo : InvalidOperation: (:) [Start-Process], InvalidOperationException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidOperationException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.StartProcessCommand

Comment: This looks to be that my $credential account from other domains/forests doesn't have the appropriate access rights to log into the computer I'm running the script from I assume from the error, so I guess I'm back to the start on how to do this with alternative accounts for each domain